# Display year in x axis of line graph highcharts

Tags: highcharts

This is how the chart looks like at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/VunVq/1/

On the x axis instead displaying the full date, I just want to display year.

e.g 2008      2009    2010

The tooltip should display the full date though.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['2008-03-31', '2009-03-31', '2010-03-31']
        },
```

I read the api reference but cannot figure out how to display only year in x axis, maybe because its past my bedtime and my mind is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `label's` `formatter` callback JavaScript function to format the label.

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['2008-03-31', '2009-03-31', '2010-03-31'],
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value.split('-')[0];
                }
            }
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/DHPZY/3/)**

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, I knew the solution was simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set type xaxis as datetime (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) and use pointStart() / pointInterval for series.